# Cannot GET / with routes defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, get

I'm having some problems here. I'm new at node.js and Rest API, but i'm trying to learn by myself. I made REST API that communicates with my database using MongoDB, I'm using Postman to test if my routes are working properly. The thing is, my routes stopped working and I have no clue why.

that's my index.js

```
const express =     require('express');
const bodyParser =  require('body-parser');
const mongoose =    require('mongoose');

//set up express app
const app = express();

//connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/usersregs', { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//parse the body before routes so teh acess is sucessfull
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//error handling middleware
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log(err);
    //res.status(450).send({err: err.message})
});

//initialize routes
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api')); 

//listen for request
app.listen(4000, function(){
    console.log('Now listening for request at port 4000');
});
```

that's my api.js, where my routes are defined

```
const express =     require('express');
const router =      express.Router();
const Users =       require('../models/users');
const Joi =         require('Joi');

//testing
router.get('/',function(req, res, next){
    res.send('hello');
});

//turning the method public
module.exports = router;
```

I'll use Joi in another route. I couldn't find any errors in my code, and it is upload no problem using "nodemon index". I tried accessind by `http://localhost:4000` and received `Cannot GET /`. I have other routes defined in my api.js, but don't matter what kind of request that I send, I always get `Cannot GET /` in response or the URL according with my request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are pulling in `./routes/api.js` onto something with `.use('/api')`, all of those routes are relative to '/api'.

So, you don't have a '/' route, but `http://localhost:4000/api/` should work.

Comment: It worked here, but one more question, how can I change my code so that `http://localhost:4000/api/` works the same as `http://localhost:4000/`. in other words, how can I remove `api` from the request?

Comment: Just remove it from `app.use()`, so either `app.use('/', require('./routes/api'));` or just `app.use(require('./routes/api'));`

Comment: I just want to let you know that everything is working fine now. Thanks!